# Sql Server Agent Job Fails

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-agent

I job that executes the package located on server. The package has logging set up. When I disable that logging it executes fine as expected but when I run that with logging it throws an error.

Information:

1. Job and Package is located on same server.
2. User have permission to execute the job.
3. Logging connections are coming from the different server.

Error:

```
Executed as user: VHRDEVLHQ3379\SYSTEM. ....50.2500.0 for 64-bit  
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. 
All rights reserved.    
Started:  5:10:13 PM

Error: 2013-11-25 17:10:14.61     
Code: 0xC0202009     
Source: Package Connection manager "HRPConfig"     
Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  
An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.  
An OLE DB record is available.  
Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  
Hresult: 0x80040E4D  
Description: "Login failed for user 'USER'.".  
End Error  

Error: 2013-11-25 17:10:14.69     
Code: 0xC0202009     
Source: Package Connection manager "Logging"     
Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  
An OLE DB error has occurred. 
Error code: 0x80040E4D.  
An OLE DB record is available.  
Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  
Hresult: 0x80040E4D  
Description: "Login failed for user 'USER'.".  
End Error  

Error: 2013-11-25 17:10:14.69     
Code: 0xC020801C     
Source: Package Log provider "SSIS log provider for SQL Server"     
Description: SSIS 
Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  
The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Logging" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.  COM error object information is available.
Source: "Package"  error code: 0xC0202009  
Description: "SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.  An OLE DB record is available.  
Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  
Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user 'USER'.".  ".  
End Error  

Error: 2013-11-25 17:10:14.71     
Code: 0xC0202009     
Source: Package Connection manager "HRPConfig"     
Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  
An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  
Hresult: 0x80040E4D  
Description: "Login failed for user 'USER'.".  
End Error  

Error: 2013-11-25 17:10:14.79     
Code: 0xC0202009     
Source: Package Connection manager "Logging"     
Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.  An OLE DB record is available.  
Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  
Hresult: 0x80040E4D  
Description: "Login failed for user 'USER'.".  
End Error  

Error: 2013-11-25 17:10:14.79     
Code: 0xC020801C     
Source: Package Log provider "SSIS log provider for SQL Server"     
Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Logging" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.  COM error object information is available.  Source: "Package"  error code: 0xC0202009  Description: "SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. 
Error code: 0x80040E4D.  An OLE DB record is available.  
Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  
Hresult: 0x80040E4D  
Description: "Login failed for user 'USER'.".  ".  
End Error  

Error: 2013-11-25 17:10:18.21     
Code: 0xC0202009     
Source: Package Connection manager "Logging"     
Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.  An OLE DB record is available.  
Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  
Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user 'USER'.".  
End Error  

Error: 2013-11-25 17:10:18.27     
Code: 0xC0202009     
Source: Package Connection manager "Logging"     
Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLED...  The package execution fa...  The step failed.
```

Comment: Have you looked at the error message you pasted above? It stands out pretty well what the issue is

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. But as I explained in information I do have access to all connections and I can't figure it out the problem.

Comment: Doesn't this give you a clue: `Login failed for user 'USER'`

Comment: Thank you all for your help. It got resolved. My job script was right but there was no permission for that SQLagent on that database as the database was fairly new and never accessed before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your SQL Server Agent Account executing the job have write permissions to the logging tables? That sounds like the issue.

Comment: Yes. It has the write permission

Comment: I would recommend reviewing the SQL Logs for failed connections. This will help to verify that you're connecting to the server that you think you're connecting to. The error message is certainly indicating a permissions issue. You could also run SQL Profiler on the database that your connecting to which would show you a failed log in, if the authentication is failing.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. It got resolved. My job script was right but there was no permission for that SQLagent on that database as the database was fairly new and never accessed before.